# How to change value of hook state in jest?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, jestjs

I'm new to jest. I'm trying to change hook state in jest.But I couldn't find any docs for implementing the same.Following is my hook state in SignIn screen.

```
const [form, setForm] = React.useState({
    email: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
    password: "",
    signUpType: SignUpType.PHONE_NUMBER,
  });
```

I want to change the state of `signUpType` to `EMAIL` while testing.How this can be achieved ?I've done the following

```
it("Email validation", () => {
    const email = "sample.s@abc.com";
    // Stub the initial state
    const stubInitialState = [{ signUpTyp: "EMAIL" }];
    React.useState = jest.fn().mockReturnValue([stubInitialState, {}]);

    const tree = mount(
      <Provider store={configureStore}>
        <SignIn />
      </Provider>
    );
    expect(tree.find('CustomTextInput[attrName="email"]').prop("value")).toBe(
      ""
    );
    expect(email).toMatch(/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,})+$/);
  });
```

But the above code is not working for me.Please help me to find a solution for this.Also the `TextInput` will be either `email` or `phoneNumebr` depending on user selection.

Comment: How would the _user_ switch the sign-up type to email? Note you really shouldn't mock React's API.

Comment: Is it because `stubInitialState` has `signUpTyp` instead of `signUpType`?

Comment: @Donut sorry that was a typo. But it is not working either. Getting this error `Method “props” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead`.  Because the initial state will be `PHONE_NUMBER` so `attrName` with `email` will be undefined , that's why I'm trying to change the state value.Please help.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `jset.fn().mockReturnValue`, but it looks like you might have an additional layer of "nesting" there; this is what you're effectively calling that method with:

`[[{ signUpTyp: "EMAIL" }], {}]`

Does `stubInitialState` need to be an object within an array? Should it just be an object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `jest.spyOn` api to mock the `React.useState` method:

```js
const stubInitialState = [{ signUpTyp: "EMAIL" }];
const mockedSetform = jest.fn();

jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockReturnValue([stubInitialState, mockedSetform]);
```

[jest.spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Comment: I've tried this method , but still getting the same issue